# Java ArrayList search using the first letter

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an ArrayList in java with a bunch of string items inside it, I want to be able to specify a single letter and in return get all of the strings that begun with the single letter that was specified.

Is there a method I can call upon which makes this process easy? or would I just have to iterate through each item in the array list at index 0?

I dont know a lot about Array Lists but the assignment I am working on requires me to use them, I hope someone can shed some light on this for me! :-)

Also I know there are similar questions on here that tell you how to search an array list, I just want to know how to do it whilst looking for the first letter of each item in the array list to see if the letter matches the letter that the user gives to it.

Comment: Can you add your code?

Comment: What do you want to return? Another `List<String>`?

Comment: I want it to return all the words from the ArrayList that match the first letter

Comment: as part of another Array List maybe?

Comment: [`String#startsWith`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith(java.lang.String)) would be a good method to use

Comment: @RonB7 you should really learn to use the documentation. The docs clearly state that there is no method in ArrayList that will let you do what you want, and it also tells you that the String class has a method called `startsWith`.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps, something like this:

```
public static List<String> getPossibleStrings(List<String> strings, String query) {
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (String s: strings) {
            if (s.startsWith(query))
             result.add(s);
        }

        return result;
 }
```

Comment: startsWith doesnt resolve as a method for me, do I have to import a library for it?

Comment: @RonB7 No, you don't need any library. It is part of the standard String methods. [String#startsWith](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith(java.lang.String))

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no java method that, given a character, will search an ArrayList and return all Strings that begin with that letter. I believe you need to  loop through the ArrayList and for each String, see if it starts with the character that you are looking for. You can get the first character of a String using the substring method:

`myString.substring(0,1);`

Answer (score 1):

If you are viewing this a few years later and startsWith isn't working or you don't wanna use it, try something like this.

```
public static int findAmount(ArrayList<String> items, String letter) {

    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
        
        if (items.get(i).substring(0, 1).equals(letter)) {

            count++;

        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

(As per substring, you will be comparing only the first char in the items.get(i) with the single char letter)

Answer (score 0):

Could use [Java 8 streams](http://winterbe.com/posts/2014/07/31/java8-stream-tutorial-examples/).

```
List<String> myList = Arrays.asList("apple", "grape");
String start = "a";
myList.stream()
    .filter(x -> x.startsWith(start))
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Outputs `apple`

Comment: startsWith doesnt resolve as a method for me, do I have to import a library for it?

Comment: No, it's part of the standard Java library for the String class. This ran perfectly fine for me in Java 8

Comment: @RonB7: Maybe your are using Java 7 and not 8?  Streams are available in Java 8 and not Java 7.

you can try solution provided by Bijay Gurung which works on Java 7

Comment: @TanmayBaid The exact same comment was posted on that answer. The problem is apparently the startWith method

Comment: @cricket_007: oops... did not notice that!

I wonder if its not actually a String then!

Comment: @TanmayBaid That's up to the OP. As I said, this code runs.